# Trouble adding Bootstrap 4 CSS with Webpack 4 in ReactJS SpringBoot Application

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, bootstrap-4, spring-tool-suite

I am getting an error where webpack is not able to resolve the bootstrap 4 css which is sitting in the node_modules directory. I have looked at a number of tutorials around webpack 4 and bootstrap 4 but I am thinking it is not in the same folder structure.

I've also tried changing the import bootstrap css trying to change the directory to push it to the node_modules directory but that does not seem to work.

***Error log from Spring Tool Suite***

*[INFO] ERROR in ./src/main/resources/static/js/app.js
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.min.css' in 'C:\sourcecode\personal-website\src\main\resources\static\js'
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/resources/static/js/app.js 26:0-46*

***webpack.config.js***

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: './src/main/resources/static/js/app.js',
performance: {
    hints: false
},
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['@babel/react', '@babel/env']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: /stylesheets|node_modules/,
            use: [ "style-loader", "css-loader" ]
        }
   ]
}
```

};

***app.js***

```
import 'bootstrap';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/boostrap.min.css';

import Landing from './components/Landing';

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Landing />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your folder structure is like. But, I believe everything is relative to the location of the file where you're importing bootstrap's css from.

Given the folder structure below

```
  sourceCode
  |--node_modules
     |--bootstrap
        |--dist
           |--css
              |--bootstrap.min.css
    |--routes
    |--src
       |--main
          |--resources
             |--static
                |--app.js
    |--dist
    |--views
```

if you're importing bootstrap's CSS stylesheet in the **app.js** script, it would go like:

```
 import '../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-min.css';
```

The double period (..) means you're moving one step up the folder structure/tree.

You did say you've tried changing your import. But, I based my answer on what you've shown.

On the other hand, try taking a look at [`VS Code`](https://code.visualstudio.com/) then check out the  [`Path Intellisense`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense) extension. It'll help you with those imports.  Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply I tried the relative path you mentioned and using the VS Code extension the change around the path for the css file but am still getting the same error. I was hoping the import would resolve to node_modules so that I wouldn't have to use the relative path.